# Hibernate saves entities even if they already exist because of generated ids

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am making an application with users. A user has an id, which is automatically assigned using the following Hibernate annotation:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id
```

That is all fine and dandy, however the problem is that every time I run the application (while adding the same user) it assigns a new id to the user, regardless if the user already exists.

What can I do that makes it so an existing user doesn't get a new id every time I run the application without having to request *all* users to check their username individually?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Some more code examples (I will only write relevant code here).

The User:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    // more code here
}
```

The User hibernate class with the save function:
(The session is opened in Main and given to the constructor).

```
public class UserDAOHibernate implements GebruikerDAO {
    private Session session;

    public UserDAOHibernate(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean save(User user) {
        try {
            if (this.findById(user.getId()) == null) {
                Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(user);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    // more code here
}
```

The above code where I check if the user already exists based on the id doesn't work because of the fact that the user keeps getting new ids. So this function checks if there exists a user with id = 2, while the one that already exists has id = 1.

In Main:

```
// lots of code

User user = new User("Stijuh");

// more code here

UserDAOHibernate udao = new UserDAOHibernate(session);
udao.save(user);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to update, before saving the object, you have to set the id field. This way Hibernate will not generate a new one

Comment: When I say saving, I mean I want it to give an error when I try to save the entity seeing as it already exists. Is there a way I can do that without having to set the id in my code?

Comment: You will have to manually check if the entity exists then and if it exists, return an error.

Comment: Then I'd have to request all entities in that database and check their attributes right? Wouldn't that significantly reduce speed after a while?

Comment: You don't need to request all entities. On every creation request, you make one query to find that specific id, which at most returns one row. Not a big performance impact. I write REST APIs on a daily basis though and I haven't had the need for such a check so far. Maybe if you share your code I can give you some alternative way to solve the problem.

Comment: When I make a request to find a user with that id, it will never find it because the hibernate annotation gives it another id, so if I save the same User, there will be two users, one with id = 1, the other with id = 2. Shall I edit my post above with some example code?

Comment: Feel free to share more code :)

Comment: I added more code :)

Comment: Okay, saw your code. But how do you know when a user is duplicated? By checking the name?

Comment: The thing is, I did something similar for a school project, and there it would give an error if the user already existed. It uses the exact same formula which is why I am confused as to why this doesn't work here. So I thought that Hibernate had a build-in way of knowing when to save an object or not. I take it Hibernate doesn;t then? :P

Comment: The thing is, you are passing a User without an id. That explicitly means you want the server to assign an id to it and save it. No matter how many times you call it, it will always create a new entity. A typical client will pass a User without id when it wants to create a user, and pass a user with an id when it wants to update it. The id is after all what allows both server and client to identify a User. If you don't want to allow two users with the same name, that is a check you will have to do yourself without saving, or alternatively delegate it to the database with a unique constraint

Comment: you can use `saveOrUpdate` instead of `save`. `save` will proceed without performing existence check, on the other hand `saveOrUpdate` will check for existence, if record exists it will be updated else a new record will be inserted.

Comment: If id is not set, save and saveOrUpdate will be no different. Both will see the entity as a new one and thus generate an id.